# Передача методом post значения checkbox-a

Tags: html, checkbox, формы

Здравствуйте.
Сижу, туплю над казалось бы простейшей задачей.

```
    <form action="" method="post">
.......
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="upakovka" value="Упаковка нужна" /> Упаковать товар</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="dostavka" value="Доставка нужна" /> Доставить до двери</label>
.......
</form>
```

Получается, что при отправке формы, не важно, чекнуты ли чекбоксы, или нет, всё равно в `$_POST['upakovka']` передаётся "Упаковка нужна", и в доставке тоже.

А нужно, чтобы если чекбокс не отмечен, ничего не передавалось.

Что я делаю не так? Спасибо.

Comment: Вопрос по html, а не php. <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> Чекед попробуйте

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_checked

Comment: @xSx спасибо за поправку, сейчас тег поменяю. А на checked не реагирует. Ставил уже. Всё то же самое.

Comment: @xSx а, понял))) у вас в примере оба чекбокса с одинаковым name, а у меня-то разные

Comment: Думаю, если все получилось, вам стоит ответить самому на свой вопрос "В духе сообщества", т.к. я особо не углублялся в вопросе и не опишу хорошо.

Comment: @xSx да вот именно, что не получилось, у вас в примере одинаковые name у обоих чекбоксов, всё работает, а у меня разные, не работает)))

Answer (score 2):

Вы не должны использовать ничего в полях типа "чекбокс" в качестве значения. А если вы хотите чтобы поле было отмечено по умолчанию, используйте слово "checked". В любом случае, когда кто-то поставит/уберет галочку на вашем чекбоксе, значение "checked" появится/исчезнет там автоматически. А рядом (когда уже закрыли тэг)  вы можете подписать что хотите Упаковка, Доставка и т.п.

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" name="delivery" checked /> Доставка</label>
```

А при отправке через "POST" вам нужно лишь проверить наличие переменной

`if ( isset($_POST['delivery']) == true ) {
     echo "Покупатель заказал доставку"; 
}`

Comment: если я убираю value, то передаётся значение on для обоих чекбоксов, а checked тут ни при чём вообще) вопрос звучит примерно так: "надо, чтобы значение чекбокса передавалось только, если он отмечен"

Comment: спасибо! то есть, без проверки наличия, никак не обойтись? я почему-то считал, что если чекбокс отмечен, то передаётся его value, а если не отмечен - null

Answer (score 0):

Не могу воспроизвести вашу проблему. Хотя код почти такой же, я только value на 1 поменял:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="upakovka" value="1">
    Упаковать товар
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="dostavka" value="1">
    Доставить до двери
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<?php

if ($_POST) {
    var_dump($_POST);
}

if (isset($_POST['upakovka'])) {
    var_dump($_POST['upakovka']);
}
```

Еще есть такой способ:

```
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="1">
```